# Can I create a prototype scoped bean with Spring Javaconfig?

Tags: java, spring

The old docs for Spring Javaconfig say that I can use

```
@Bean(scope=DefaultScopes.PROTOTYPE)
```

to get a prototype bean, but Spring 3.0.5's `@Bean` doesn't seem to have this property.

Is there any way to control the scope of a bean in Javaconfig?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Use `@Scope` instead](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html).

Also, `DefaultScopes` is not available in Spring core, but you can use `BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE` and `BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON` for convenience.

Comment: Thanks, it was proving surprisingly difficult to Google for!

Comment: Its now `ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE`

Answer (score 2):

You can add `@Scope("prototype")` for example:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public DemoDao getDao() {
    DemoDao dao = new DemoDao();
    dao.setAddress("annoted:address");
    dao.setName("annoted:name");
    return dao;
}
```

Comment: You should explain why OP should do that. Also if you comment more code, why not put it into the answer so people see it immediately? :)

Comment: Like what I just did ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following for Java config,

```
@Bean
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public SpringBean springBean(){
    SpringBean bean = new SpringBean();
    return bean;
}
```

Or simply,

```
@Scope(value = "prototype")
```

Refer [@Scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html) annotation